# Не билдится .apk файл в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Всем привет! Проблема в том, что при нажатии "Run" запускается эмулятор, но потом выдается ошибка:

> Unexpected Error: 
>            Local path doesn't exist. Local path doesn't exist. The project
>   may need to be synced with Gradle
>   files.

Пробовал синхронизировать, как подсказывает сама студия, - не помогает, в том месте, куда он ссылается, просто нет .apk файла. После rebuild также ничего не меняется. =(

Много всего перерыл на stackoverflow, но пока ничего не помогает. Версия tools и самой студии последние.
Может, проблема в том, что у меня на работе прокси, и я где-то что-то не донастроил? Help!

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.evgenbak.crowcounter"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

Gradle console:

> Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
>
> Configuration on demand is an
>   incubating feature. :app:preBuild
>   :app:compileDebugNdk
>   :app:preDebugBuild
>   :app:checkDebugManifest
>   :app:preReleaseBuild
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72103Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareDebugDependencies
>   :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugRenderscript
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugAssets
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugAssets
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugResValues
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugResources
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugResources
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:processDebugManifest
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:processDebugResources
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugSources
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugJava
>   :app:preDexDebug FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an
>   exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
>
>   > java.lang.IllegalStateException: dx is missing
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info
>     or --debug option to get more log
>     output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 4.902 secs

SDK Manager:

[image]

**Обновление**

Версия стоит последняя 24.0.2, судя по SDK Manager
PS: почищу наши комменты, а то новые нельзя создавать...

Установлены не все. Win, кстати, х64. Добавил в вопрос скрин SDK Manager

Да, 1.0.2
Дома, у меня тоже все запускается, а вот на работе - проблема. Единственное отличие между домом и работой, что на работе стоит прокси. Я уже неделю назад зашел в тупик, поэтому решил сюда написать...

Переустановил Tools, никаких ошибок не было. Может, я изначально что-то не так делаю? Или где-то накосячил?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем это единственный официальный ответ по такой ошибке [Android Open Source Project](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=83163&can=1&q=java.lang.IllegalStateException%3A%20dx%20is%20missing&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars).
Вроде как пофиксили в версии 24.0.2. Проблема в SDK, поэтому рекомендую его переустановить.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь(не могу проголосовать). Как оказалось все банальнее =( Я уже говорил, что пытаюсь запустить студию на работе, так вот, у нас тут каспер стоит, и мы потом только догадались посмотреть по логам на сервере, что это он блокировал там какой-то процесс. Вопрос можно закрыть.